# Android app force closing after press save button on alertDialog

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

When user press start button, popup is opening which ask to enter name, by this name audio will be stored in SD card.

Now my problem is when user press save button on alert Dialog an error is occurring saying that `java.lang.IllegalStateException and android app force closing`

Record activity code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Record extends Activity {
String audioName= "";

private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";

private MediaRecorder recorder = null;

Chronometer myChronometer;
Handler seekHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);


    myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    Button recordingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);


    recordingButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Record.this,
                    "Start Recording With LongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            enableButtons(true);
            startRecording();
            return true;
        }
    });
    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);

}

private void setButtonHandlers() {
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);

}

private void enableButton(int id, boolean isEnable) {
    ((Button) findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}

private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
    enableButton(R.id.btnStart, !isRecording);
    enableButton(R.id.btnStop, isRecording);
}

private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + audioName +  ".wav");
}

private void startRecording() {
    displayAlertDialog();


}

private void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
        myChronometer.stop();
    }
}



private void displayAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Record.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Would you Like to save your Recording");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Audio Name");

    final EditText editTextAudioName = new EditText(Record.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    editTextAudioName.setLayoutParams(lp);
    alertDialog.setView(editTextAudioName);


    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                    audioName = editTextAudioName.getText().toString().trim();
                    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
                    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
                    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);


                    try {
                        recorder.prepare();
                        recorder.start();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    myChronometer.start();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.show();
}


    private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Toast.makeText(Record.this, "Error: " + what + ", " + extra,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Toast.makeText(Record.this,
                "Warning: " + what + ", " + extra, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnStart: {
                Toast.makeText(Record.this, "Start Recording",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                enableButtons(true);
                startRecording();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.btnStop: {
                Toast.makeText(Record.this, "Stop Recording",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                enableButtons(false);
                stopRecording();
                // displayFormatDialog();
                break;
            }


        }
    }
};
}
```

And  my logcat

in line 138 = recorder.start();

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.framesss.myproject, PID: 2254
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                              at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.example.framesss.myproject.Record$3.onClick(Record.java:138)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

do you add permission in your mannifest?

```
<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" / >
```